# Does the subnet mask have to be the same on two devices connected by ethernet?

Tags: networking, subnet

I have 2 devices, a box(we'll call this a router) and a device that connects to the router by ethernet.

**Router**

IP address: 10.114.76.2

Ethernet IP: 192.168.1.1

Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

**Device 1**

LAN IP: 192.168.1.1

IP address: 10.10.6.106

Subnet Mask: 255.255.252.0

On the router, I port forward Device 1 so we can access device 1 through the router. For example: We port forward port 81 to 10.10.6.106 and port 80 so we can access device 1 by typing in 10.114.76.2:81.

In most cases this works fine but in this particular instance, I am having trouble connecting them. All other times I have set this up the subnet masks were the same but in this case, the subnet mask of the device 1 is different. In this particular setup, would the subnet mask be the problem? Do they both devices have to have the same subnet mask to connect to each other?

Comment: In describing these two devices, you refer to their IP addressing using different terminologies. You refer to an IP address and Ethernet IP on your "Router", and then an IP address and a LAN IP in "Device 1". It's not clear to me how these networks are related. Are Ethernet IP, LAN IP and IP address here all on different networks? Additionally, you've listed the same IP, 192.168.1.1, on each device. I'd consider editing your question to address these questions to receive a clear answer to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Each IP-address has its own netmask. A netmask is not defined per "device".
One possible notation is a suffix to the IP-address, e.g.: "/24", which equals a netmask of "255.255.255.0".

Referring to your post, see the following example:

**Router**
IP address: 10.114.76.2/22 (255.255.252.0)
Ethernet IP: 192.168.1.1/24 (255.255.255.0)

**Device 1**
LAN IP: 192.168.1.1/24 (255.255.255.0)
IP address: 10.10.6.106/22 (255.255.252.0)

It seems unclear, why your "Device 1" has two IP-addresses and why your Router has the same IP-address (192.168.1.1). Assuming both are connected through the network 192.168.1.0/24 then each device must have a separate IP-address, e.g.: 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.2/24.

Within one IP-segment (e.g. 192.168.1.0) it is highly preferrable that all connected devices share the identical netmask within this range. This means that all devices within this IP-setment should have a netmask of 255.255.255.0 (same as /24).

If your device is configured with additional IP-addresses from other IP-segments, then these other IP-addresses can have different netmask, just as in the example above.